gcloud publish Pub/Sub JSON message where JSON properties contain space characters
I have a JSON file named countries/list.json I want to publish the content with gcloud CLI.
{
  "countries": [
   {
      "id": "SE",
      "name": "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "id": "UK",
      "name": "United Kingdom"
    }
  ]
}

Accoring to the CLI docs I should be able to use
gcloud pubsub topics publish projects/<PROJECT>/topics/<TOPIC>--message=$(jq -c "." countries/list.json) --attribute "Content-Type=application/json"

This results in
ERROR: (gcloud.pubsub.topics.publish) unrecognized arguments: Kingdom"}]} 

If I change "United Kingdom" to "United-Kingdom" it works, but that is not what I want.

Try --message="$(jq -c . countries/list.json)"

The CLI gives me a messageIds: <NUMBER>, which accepts the command. But the body is empty in my receiver (API with push subscription).

Closest I got before I gave up and solved it with Node and JS was
PROJECT_ID=$1
TOPIC=TOPIC
DATA=$(cat countries/list.json | jq -c | sed -e 's/ /\\u0002/g')
ATTRIBUTES=Content-Type=application/json
gcloud pubsub topics publish projects/$PROJECT_ID/topics/$TOPIC --message $DATA --attribute $ATTRIBUTES
`
